# Find Even/Odd number without using mathematical/bitwise operator in Java

Tags: java

How is it possible find Even/Odd number without using mathematical/bitwise operator?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? How have you not succeeded so far?

Comment: can loop be used? you just want to find any 5 odd or even number starting from 1?

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]?  If so, it'd pay to tag it as such.

Comment: @sarnold i make just simple java programm to find odd/even no using operator but i need some hint in to make programm without using operator..

Comment: I simply don't understand why teachers should give such a problem that is far far away from real programming. Is there any language in the world that does not have mathematical operator?

Comment: @taskinoor You're quite right although this exercise is a pretty bad one sometimes you want to try and get people to do a little thinking outside the box sometimes which is why you see assignments with arbitrary constraints (that to us don't make sense sometimes). There are probably far better examples restricting you to only use bitwise operators or something of the sort.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, if bitwise operation were allowed than I would have no problem. But the title says that is also not allowed.

Comment: @taskinoor I know I'm saying this is a bad example but exercises that are of this style are usually good thinking exercises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you allowed to cheat by going to a simpler, rather than trickier, solution than the standard `i % 2 == 0`? :) And secondarily, are you allowed to cheat by calling a JDK method which uses arithmetic or bitwise ops? If so, you could:

- get the int as a String
- look at the last char
- use that char in a switch
- return true iff that last char is '0', '2', '4', '6' or '8'.

Comment: I disavowed 6 after it ran over my dog. Six is dead to me! But... thanks for the catch. :-)

Comment: You can't convert to a String without mathematical/bitwise operators.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Anything in every Programming Language is a String, so we won't convert that into Integer at the first place. So the rest of the steps as described in the answer can do the trick.  Regards

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits String is not a primitive type either in Java, the JVM or in machine code. Its all numbers. `char` are 16-bit unsigned integers. String is a construct.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : I mean what ever we getting as an input from the user, is read as String in the first place, isn't that right ?

Comment: When you read from stdin you have a stream of bytes which are decoded as chars. The user only types one character at a time, not a string.  When you get many chars e.g. a line, you can build a String from this.  All this takes arithmetic operations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's why I asked whether it's okay to cheat by jdk method that itself uses mathematical/bitwise operators. If you get down to it, there's nothing you can do that *isn't* a bitwise operation. (I'm assuming the OP isn't running a JVM on a quantum computer.)

Comment: @yshavit, I agree that's the only way you can answer the question. Otherwise the question doesn't make sense. ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
    int value = 7;

    String message = String.format("Is %s odd or even?",value);
    Object[] options = {"Odd","Even"};
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            message,
            "Is It Odd Or Even",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[0]);
    System.out.println(String.format("%s is %s", value, options[n]));
```

The original question doesn't give the size of the data set.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a really weird arbitrary condition but what the heck. Just convert it to a string and check if the last character is a 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8.

Comment: You can't convert to a String without mathematical/bitwise operators.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not if you read the number from standard input as a string :)

Comment: I would count comparison and an arithmetic operator, and I doubt you can read from standard input without implicitly performing one of the banned operators. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess that's relaxing the definition of arithmetic since you're just testing for equality

Comment: equality performs a subtraction and determines if the results is zero (in machine code)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know but computers are just oversized calculators so you might as well just call it impossible at this point :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is, you can't.

Any solution might consider will be composed of bitwise or mathematical operators.  You can call or write a method which hides this from you, but it uses operators all the same.

---

you can do

```
public static boolean isOdd(int n) {
    return (n << -1) < 0;
}
```

Comment: I think a shift is a bitwise or mathematical operator.

Comment: Yeah, and I commented as much on another post but it was deleted. << is more obviously one, so I picked it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below java code.

```
String[] sarr = {"Odd Number","Even Number"};

int num = 7;

int x = num%2;

System.out.println(sarr[x]);
```

Comment: I expect your professor will fail this because `%` is most definitely a mathematical operator.

Comment: See [Language Basics - Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following ways to check if a number is odd, listed in order of performance:

```java
// Using bit-manipulation (fastest)
boolean odd = ((num & 1) == 1);

// Using remainder (fast, but division is slower than bit-manipulation)
boolean odd = ((num % 2) == 1);

// Using conversion to string (very slow, but doesn't use any operators)
boolean odd = Integer.toString(num, 2).endsWith("1");
```